# Flutter - How to control profile image size in the drawer

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to control the profile image size, and get it rounded instead of oval as shown below.

Changing the height and/or the width values doesn't affect neither the size nor the ratio, also the weird thing is when I change the margin parameter it changes the oval shape radius.

```
new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
  currentAccountPicture: new Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0),
    width: 10.0,
    height: 10.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      image: new DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        image: new NetworkImage(
          "https://example.com/assets/images/john-doe.jpg",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  accountName: new Container(
    ...
  ),
  accountEmail: new Container(
    ...
  ),
  onDetailsPressed: () {
    ...
  },
),
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

**Update**: The above way of doing is a workaround to the CircleAvatar that didn't give any control on the image size. If you tried CircleAvatar in some different way that gives control on image size, please share it to help.

Answer (score 5):

Use This code for network image:

```
                new CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 60.0,
                      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF778899),
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage("Your Photo Url"), // for Network image

                    ),
```

Use this for asset Image:

```
              new CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 60.0,
                      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF778899),
                      child: new Image.asset(
                        'images/profile.png',
                      ), //For Image Asset

                    ),
```

Comment: I have tried the above solution as workaround, because CircleAvatar didn't give me any control on the image size. Do you have any idea for the size?

Answer (score 4):

If you use backgroundImage as the image provider for CircleAvatar then changing the radius property indeed has no effect. From the source `circle_avatar.dart` it can be observed the image is being rendered as BoxFit.cover `DecorationImage(image: backgroundImage, fit: BoxFit.cover)` - and in `user_accounts_drawer_header.dart` the `currentAccountPicture` is hardcoded to be a 72.0 pixel SizedBox so the image will always be 72.0px in dimensions.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/user_accounts_drawer_header.dart#L57

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/circle_avatar.dart#L203

Hopefully the Flutter team adds some level of control to this in the future.

Not an answer, just more info that hopefully helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppDrawerState createState() => new _AppDrawerState();
}

class _AppDrawerState extends State<AppDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Drawer(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
              currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50.0,
                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF778899),
                backgroundImage:
                    NetworkImage("http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the screenshot of output:

[image]

Comment: My drawer is child of a big home scaffold, same level as appbar and body, if I use you code I need to move all the drawer code outside of the build widget, then I am not sure how to call it from the current place ?

Comment: Use this code:  drawer: new Drawer(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50.0,
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF778899),
                  backgroundImage:
                      NetworkImage("http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

Comment: Sorry nothing happens when I change the radius value.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your image in a [CircleAvatar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html) widget. It’s made for such purposes.

Comment: I have tried that previously with radius value as parameter, but could get no control on the image size.

Comment: Had some trouble with images size as well but it was due to using a Stack Widget and not wrapping the CircleAvatar in a Positioned widget

Answer (score 1):

You put the margin inside the Container of the image while you have to use the margin parameter of the UserAccountDrawerHeader, this is why your image became an oval:

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0),                                            
          currentAccountPicture: Container(  
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image:
                        NetworkImage("https://via.placeholder.com/150"))),
          ),
          accountName: new Container(
              child: Text(
            'Name',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          )),
          accountEmail: new Container(
              child: Text(
            'Email',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          )),
        ),
```

Comment: You're right about the margin, what about the image size control ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own header:

```
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue
              ),
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  return ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    child: Image.asset('images/myImage.jpg'),
                  ),
                  //These can go here or below the header with the same background color
                  Text("user name"),//customize this text
                  Text("useremail@example.com"),
                  //...additional header items here 
                ],
              )),
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution!!!**  at least thats what worked for me

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          // Side menu
          drawer: new Drawer(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                    accountName: new Text('Hymn +'),
                    accountEmail: new Text('johndoe@gmail.com'),
                    currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(
                          'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*uC0kYhn8zRx8Cfd0v0cYQg.jpeg'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
          DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  /*CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 50.0,
                    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF778899),
                    child: new Image.asset('assets/images/profile_image.png'), //For Image Asset
                  ),*/
                  Container(
                    height: 110,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                      child: Image.asset('assets/images/profile_image.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  //These can go here or below the header with the same background color
                  //Divider(height: 1.0, thickness: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
                  SizedBox(height: 9.0),
                  Text("user name"),
                  //...additional header items here
                ],
              ),
          ),
```

[image]